# xUnit integration tests get slower over time

Tags: .net-core, integration-testing, xunit

I am using xUnit's `Theory`, reading data from a JSON file and testing an endpoint, like this:

```
public class TranslatorControllerTest : BaseIntegrationTest
{
    private const string BaseEndpoint = "/api/translator";

#pragma warning disable CS8618
    public class TestCase
    {
        public string Input { get; set; }
        public Output Output { get; set; }
    }

    public class Output
    {
        public string En { get; set; }
        public string Fr { get; set; }
        public string Pt { get; set; }
        public string It { get; set; }
        public string De { get; set; }

        public static IEnumerable<string> GetLanguages()
        {
            return typeof(Output).GetProperties().Select(field => field.Name);
        }
    }
#pragma warning restore CS8618

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData()
    {
        string filePath = "path-to-json.json";
        var jsonCache = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        List<TestCase> testCases = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestCase>>(jsonCache);

        IEnumerable<string> languages = Output.GetLanguages();

        foreach(var testCase in testCases)
        {
            foreach (var language in languages)
            {
                yield return new object[] { testCase.Input, language, testCase.Output };
            }
        }
    }

    [Theory(Timeout = 2000)]
    [MemberData(nameof(TestData))]
    public async Task Translator_Should_Return_Expected_Translation(string input, string language, Output output)
    {
        try
        {
            TranslatorCommand body = new(
                original: input,
                lang: (Language)Enum.Parse(typeof(Language), language)
            );
            JsonContent jsonContent = JsonContent.Create(body);
            var response = await HttpClient.PostAsync(BaseEndpoint, jsonContent);
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);

            var lang = typeof(Output).GetProperty(language)?.GetValue(output)?.ToString();
            Assert.Equal(lang, responseBody);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

In short, this calls an endpoint which translates an input to a language and returns an output. There are in total about 18000 tests in the suite. The tests DO NOT get harder or bigger or anything as they progress, they are in no special order.

First tests run okay, but as the test cases progress, they start running slower and there are some timeouts. Interesting finds below:

```
11919)   Translator_Should_Return_Expected_Translated_Text(input: "Silicona", language: "It", output: Output { De = "Silikon", En = "Silicone", Fr = "Silicone", It = "Silicone", Pt = "Silicone" }) 
      Duración: 2,7 min

      Mensaje: 
        Assert.Fail(): The operation was canceled.

      Seguimiento de la pila: 
        TranslatorControllerTest.Translator_Should_Return_Expected_Translated_Text(String input, String language, Output output) línea 125
        --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

Of course this test should not take 2,7 minutes. Other tests may fail with this message:

```
Translator_Should_Return_Expected_Translated_Text(_input/output is irrelevant, it is a short sentence_) 
      Duración: 1 ms

      Mensaje: 
        System.InvalidOperationException : Timed out waiting for the entry point to build the IHost after 00:05:00. This timeout can be modified using the 'DOTNET_HOST_FACTORY_RESOLVER_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS' environment variable.

      Seguimiento de la pila: 
        HostingListener.CreateHost()
        <>c__DisplayClass10_0.<ResolveHostFactory>b__0(String[] args)
        DeferredHostBuilder.Build()
        WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
        WebApplicationFactory`1.ConfigureHostBuilder(IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
        WebApplicationFactory`1.EnsureServer()
        WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateDefaultClient(DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
        WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateClient(WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions options)
        BaseIntegrationTest.ctor() línea 12
        TranslatorControllerTest.ctor()
        RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions)
```

What might be happening here?

Comment: It may be possible that an error in one test case has led to a time-out in another case.

Comment: All tests pass except for those that get canceled @HungryWolf

Comment: Do you have all the test cases in the same class?

Comment: Yes, it is a theory with just one function and about 18k test cases in total. @HungryWolf

Comment: 18K. That's a very big number for a single function.  Can you break it into logical units and test it?